# How to implement mixins in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, mixins

How to implement [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) in the OCaml module system.

The closest I achieved is to use the following methodology, which I illustrate on a `MixinFormat` which adds usual output functions `print`, `output` and `to_string` on a mixin able to `format`.

Assume that we implement a module `MixinFormat` with the following signature:

```
module MixinFormat :
sig
(** Formatable mixin. *)

(** Input signature of the functor [MixinFormat.Make]. *)
module type Basis =
sig

  type t
  (** The type of formatted elements. *)

  val format : Format.formatter -> t -> unit
  (** [format fft a] pretty prints [a] on [fft]. *)

end

(** Output signature of the functor [MixinFormat.Make]. *)
module type Methods =
sig
  type t

  val to_string : t -> string
  (** Convert to string. *)

  val output : out_channel -> t -> unit
  (** Output on the given output channel. *)

  val print : t -> unit
  (** Output on the standard output channel. *)

end

(** Functor implementing output mixins based on a format definition. *)
module Make(B:Basis): Methods
  with type t := B.t

(** Signature of formatable mixins. *)
module type S =
sig
  type t
  include Basis with type t := t
  include Methods with type t := t
end
end
```

We can now use it to add common output functions to a module able to `format`, as in:

```
module Date =
struct
   module Prototype =
   struct
      type t = int * int * int
      let format ppt (y,m,d) =
        Format.fprintf ppt "%04d-%02d-%02d" y m d
   end
   include Prototype
   include MixinFormat.Make(Prototype)
end
```

This works very well but has the convenient that it is not easily iterable: if a second mxin expects functions added to `Prototype` by `MixinFormat.Make` then we need to pack `Prototype` and `MixinFormat.Make(Prototype)` in `Prototype2` which is a bit clumsy and hinders readability.

Is there an alternative implementation of mixins which could avoid to introduce a `Prototype2` when iteratively using mixins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to avoid multiple definitions of the type `t`, your functor should probably be defined as:

```
module Make(B:Basis): Methods with type t := B.t
```

To avoid having to create inner modules, you can use recursive modules like this:

```
module rec Date : sig
  type t = int * int * int
  include Basis with type t := t
  include Methods with type t := t
end = struct
  type t = int * int * int

  let format ppt (y,m,d) =
    Format.fprintf ppt "%04d-%02d-%02d" y m d

  include Make(Date)
end
```

However, it is worth noting that recursive modules can be a bit tricky. For example, if any of the values in your module (e.g. `format`) were not functions then this definition would not work.

It is also worth noting that OCaml's object system has excellent support for mixins. For examples, see [Chapter 12 of Real World OCaml](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/classes.html#mixins).